# Angular2 date validation pattern for dd/mm/yyyy for reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript

```
this.seedFundForm = this.fb.group({
    multipleSource: this.fb.array([]),
    amount:[data.amount, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]*'), Validators.maxLength(10)])],
    date:[data.date, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[0-9]{4}$/'), Validators.maxLength(10)])]
});
```

This way I have used but still I don't find a solution. Is my regular expression wrong or am I making any other mistake?

Comment: Not sure about the validity of your regex, but it would probably be better to validate the date by attempting to parse it into a date. The regex would tell you if it's in the right format, but not whether it is a valid date.

Comment: Ok for that should i use any custome validator or do we have any predefined for angular2

Comment: You regex seems good, maybe that's how you give it to the `pattern` function that is a problem. Did you try delete the first and last slashes ?

Comment: @trichetriche wow it works!! Thanks for that but what is it with the slashes

Comment: You're welcome, I'll post an answer so you can mark it as resolved. I guess that `pattern` takes a string as a parameter, to build it into a regex. This means that if you put slashes in your string, they will be considered as characters to search by the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete the first and last slashes in your string.

I guess that `pattern` takes a string as a parameter, to build it into a regex. This means that if you put slashes in your string, they will be considered as characters to search by the regex.

Comment: This correctly answers the regex question, however, as mentioned in the comments to the original question, this will validate the string for the proper date format, but will not ensure that the string represents a valid date. To do that, one would have to actually parse the date in the validator.